# Sending packets on a defined Ethernet Interface

Tags: c, sockets, packets

I have 2 Ethernet interfaces configured in my Linux Machine.
Lets say Interface A and Interface B.

I am writing a tcp client socket program and need to send the packets on the defined interface.

For example.

./client -intf interface A/B

if it the input is interface A, then the client has to send packets only  via interface A and vice versa.

Could anyone provides some hint on how to implement this?.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do something similar before, have you tried this?
https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/

Comment: I have seen this. I need little more information. If i dont provide the interface name, my application has to use the default routing. How  can implement this i dont give interface name.?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `bind()` before you call `connect()` to bind your client socket to a particular IP address.  You can use `getifaddrs()` to list the interfaces and their associated IP addresses.

Comment: Hello thanks for the input. Could you provide little more information.

Comment: @Saravana: Call `getifaddrs()` to find the mapping from interface names to IP addresses.  Create a `sockaddr_in` / `sockaddr_in6` structure with the IP address of the interface you want to use and a port of 0, and pass that to `bind()` on your socket before you call `connect()`.

Comment: thank you so much caf. So in bind we are binding to the ip address of the Ip interface. but where shall we provide the server Ip actually it needs to connect?.

Comment: @Saravana: In `connect()`, as normal.